# How to connect many database to NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to re-program my product to use two, three or more databases in my project.

Now I have one MSSQL database, product connect to this database by Nhibernate (standard `hibernate.cfg.xml` file with one connection-string).

I do not want to separate records in tables by unique identifier.

Can I manage that?

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">
   Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Application.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to do this, two of them are:

1. Use for each database a different configuration/session factory
2. If the database are on the same database server you can put the database name in mapping: databasename.dto.TableName